# What type is `peripherals.APB_SARADC.split()`?

Tags: rust, embedded, hal, peripherals

In [Demystifying .. Split..](https://apollolabsblog.hashnode.dev/demystifying-rust-embedded-hal-split-and-constrain-methods) and [.. using the ADC](https://apollolabsblog.hashnode.dev/esp32-embedded-rust-at-the-hal-analog-temperature-sensing-using-the-adc) blog:

```
// Promote ADC peripheral to HAL-level Struct
let analog = peripherals.APB_SARADC.split();
```

But I cannot figure out what the return type is of `.split()` or even for sure what definition it is using.  rust-analyzer has no tooltip for `split` and "No type definition found for "`split`".  Tooltip for `analog` just says `let analog: {unknown}`.

I can then use it in this code which builds and runs without panicking (although I'm trying to debug stuff)

```
// Create handle for ADC, configuring clock, and passing configuration handle
    let mut adc = ADC::adc(
        &mut system.peripheral_clock_control,
        analog.adc1,                               // <<< "no definition found for `adc1`
        adc_config,
    )
    .unwrap();
```

ADC::adc wants a `adc_instance: impl crate::peripheral::Peripheral<P = ADCI> + 'd` for that parameter, but I haven't been able to adapt that to an accepted explicit type annotation on `analog`.

If rust doesn't know what analog is, why isn't there a compilation error?  What type is it?

Comment: Needs more context. What are the relevant crates? What type is `peripherals.APB_SARADC`? `ADC` is sadly not very unique in the embedded world.

Comment: The first link seems to be using the stm32f4xx-hal crate while the second link (and your code) seem to be using the esp32c3-hal crate. Confusing me and maybe you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [esp32c3-hal](https://crates.io/crates/esp32c3-hal) crate, then [`.split()`](https://docs.rs/esp32c3-hal/latest/esp32c3_hal/peripherals/struct.APB_SARADC.html#method.split) is provided on the `APB_SARADC` type via the `SarAdcExt` trait. The resulting type of `analog` would be [`AvailableAnalog`](https://docs.rs/esp32c3-hal/latest/esp32c3_hal/analog/struct.AvailableAnalog.html).

Its hard to tell why rust-analyzer is having issues deducing the type, but the compiler should be trusted over it, so there's clearly no type issue with your code.